# What policy do I need to add to a IAM group to allow access to Amazon Product API

Tags: amazon-iam, amazon-product-api

While trying to follow the advice given when first accessing the IAM console I created a new user and a group to hold that user.

But I've not been able to find a suitable Policy to add to the group to allow the user access to the Amazon Product API.

Can anybody point me at the right Policy so I don't have to use my Root Key/Token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> IAM roles are not currently supported. You must use the root account credentials.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/GSG/GettingStarted.html

This is an admittedly odd use of the phrase "IAM *roles*," since an [IAM role means something different, in proper IAM terminology](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html) than the usage, here, suggests... but **"you must use the root account credentials"** seems to confirm that IAM *users* aren't supported, either... so there is no policy you can create that will enable an IAM user to access this particular service.

It seems as if perhaps the term *IAM roles* has been casually substituted in the documentation in place of the (perhaps) more accurate term *IAM identities*.